# number of comparisons for bubble sort

Tags: algorithm

I learned the number of comparisons for bubble sort is

> (n - 1) + (n - 2) + (n - 3) + ... + 2 + 1

How does it change like this?

> (n - 1) * n/2

Could you explain it?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetic_progression#Sum

Comment: Append zero as the last element. Now add the first element to the last one, the second to the second from the back, the third to the third one from the back and so on. You'll get `n/2` pairs that add up to `n-1`: `n-1+0`, `n-2+1`, `n-3+2`, etc.

Comment: this link helps me...http://www.csee.umbc.edu/courses/undergraduate/341/fall98/frey/ClassNotes/Class7/analysis.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sum of

```
1 + 2 + 3 + 4 + .... + n = n * (n + 1)/2
```

So the sum of

```
1 + 2 + 3 + .. + (n-1) = (n - 1) * n/2
```